# How can I write an if statement using a variable in a foreach loop using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm running the `foreach` loop below in my code right now, and it works great. However, I'd prefer to have it send one single email at the end of the script if the condition is met, instead of an email for each problem found. How can I do this?

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $DT = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LocalTime -ComputerName $server
  $DateTime = (Get-Date -Day $DT.Day -Month $DT.Month -Year $DT.Year -Minute $DT.Minute -Hour $DT.Hour -Second $DT.Second)
  $SUTC = $DateTime.ToUniversalTime()
  $now = Get-Date
  $NUTC = $now.ToUniversalTime()
  $Difference = (New-TimeSpan -Start ($NUTC) -End  ($SUTC))
  Write-Host "Time at $server is $SUTC. Time difference of $Difference."
  if ($Difference -ge '00:03:00') {
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Time Report -$(get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyy")" -Body "Time difference of more then 3 minutes detected." -SmtpServer "SMTPSERVER" -From "admin@firm.com" -To "group@firm.com" -UseSsl
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an array before the foreach and add messages. Then call Send-MailMessage after your foreach. Example:

```
$errors =  @()   

foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $DT = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LocalTime -ComputerName $server
  $DateTime = (Get-Date -Day $DT.Day -Month $DT.Month -Year $DT.Year -Minute $DT.Minute -Hour $DT.Hour -Second $DT.Second)
  $SUTC = $DateTime.ToUniversalTime()
  $now = Get-Date
  $NUTC = $now.ToUniversalTime()
  $Difference = (New-TimeSpan -Start ($NUTC) -End  ($SUTC))
  Write-Host "Time at $server is $SUTC. Time difference of $Difference."
  if ($Difference -ge '00:03:00') {
    $errors += "Time difference of more then 3 minutes detected."
  } 
}

if($errors.Count -gt 0) {
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Time Report -$(get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyy")" -Body ($errors -join "`n") -SmtpServer "SMTPSERVER" -From "admin@firm.com" -To "group@firm.com" -UseSsl
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Appending to an array in a loop is bound to perform poorly, because each time the array is re-created with size+1, and all existing elements are copied to the new instance. Instead just echo inside the loop and assign the loop output to a variable (`$var = foreach ($server in $servers) { ... }`).

Comment: imo, append to an array will be a problem just for large data. But that don't  deny your warning.

Comment: True, for small amounts of data it usually isn't noticable, but you don't gain anything either.